# rollback the persistence in both documents if either one throw exception while creating new doc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating signup form to insert data into users of firebase authentication and additional data into users document. Following is the action for signup.

```
export const signUp = (newUser) => {
    return async(dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
      const firebase = getFirebase();
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      
      try{
        const {user} = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          newUser.email, 
          newUser.password
        );
        if(user)
        {
          const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
          const snapshot = await userRef.get();
          if(!snapshot.exists) {
            try{
              await userRef.set({
                firstName: newUser.firstName,
                lastName: newUser.lastName,
                initials: newUser.firstName[0] + newUser.lastName[0],
                dob: newUser.dob
              })
              dispatch({ type: 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS' });
            }
            catch(err){
              throw new Error(`user creating error:${err}`)
            }
          }
          else{
            throw new Error(`Authenticate user not created`)
          }
        }
        else{
          throw new Error(`Authenticate user not able to create", error`)
        }
      }
      catch(err){
        dispatch({ type: 'SIGNUP_ERROR', err});
      }
      
  }
}
```

I am trying to force to insert data into both documents or either of them if errors accurs at somepoint. for example, if I have passed wrong value into const userRef, insertion into authentication users should be cancelled but above code is not working.

Comment: I only see one document being written here via `userRef`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "both documents".  Firebase Auth user accounts are not Firestore documents.

Comment: I mean one is firebase authentication users and another is users documents

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Firebase Auth user account, the only way to "roll it back" is by making a call to delete that account using [User.delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#delete).  There are no transactions that can automatically undo Auth operations.  And there is no way to create a single "transaction" that works across Firebase products.

For your specific case, if you want to delete the user if the document write fails, you will have to call `user.delete()` in the catch block for `userRef.set()`.